# Bokeh showing epochs on x-asis instead of "normal" dates

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a little pandas dataframe I like to plot via Bokeh. Everything works fine, except for the x-axis showing a Unix-time (I guess it's that).
The dtype of my timestamp-column is datetime64[ns, UTC].
When I print the column, I get "normal" dates : 2020-07-20 17:01:21.181000+00:00

[image: x-axis of Bokeh-plot]

I already read some posts on converting the format using pd.datetime, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/43717871/564509:

```py
p = figure(..., x_axis_type='datetime', ...)
```